# Store logical conditions programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I would like to be able to add and test logical conditions from a user interface. A logical condition can be any combination of ands / ors. like these two examples:

**Example 1: (a AND b) OR c**

**Example 2: (a OR b OR c) AND ((d AND e) OR (f AND g))**

I can create the logical conditions programatically like below but my question is how do I create an interface so that the user can create the conditions. It does not have to be very userfriendly, but in the  GUI (winform) I would like the to be able to type something in a textBox or similair to describe the conditions.

So if the user types this in a textBox **(a && b) || c** or this **(a || b || c) && ((d && e) || (f && g))** . Then I programatically shall be able to determine if the conditions are true or false (a-e is allready defined in the code)

I hope that someone can understand what I mean :-)

```
public class And
{
    public bool[] ands;
    public And(bool[] _ands)
    {
        ands = _ands;
    }

    public bool result()
    {
        foreach (bool b in ands) {
            if(b == false)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
public class Or 
{
    public bool[] ors;
    public Or(bool[] _ors)
    {
        ors = _ors;
    }

    public bool result()
    {
        foreach (bool b in ors)
        {
            if (b == true)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class test{
 
    public test() {
        bool a = true;
        bool b = false;
        bool c = true;
        bool d = true;
        bool e = false;
        bool f = true;
        bool g = true;

        bool example1 = new Or(new bool[] { new And(new bool[] {a, b}).result(), new And(new bool[] { c }).result() }).result();

        bool abc = new Or(new bool[] { a, b, c }).result();
        bool ce = new And(new bool[] { d,e }).result();
        bool fg = new Or(new bool[] { f,g }).result();
        bool de_fg = new Or(new bool[] { ce,fg }).result();

        bool example2 = new And(new bool[] { abc, de_fg}).result();

    }
}
```

Comment: As other answers tell, you should parse the input. But if the syntax is really and, ors, and parentheses you could try to write your own mini-parser. Ands and ors are just adding new operations, while parentheses are for nesting expressions. Just do not go typical route "how do I parse this with regular expressions" because you can't :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`Linq.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-6.0) or using [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0)

If you use the `Linq.Expression`, then you will need to implement your own expression provider or build your own `Expression` and use it immediately into any `Linq` extensions. So, you'll be able to convert into lambda expression, which then you can execute at any given Linq extension.

If you use `DataColumn.Expression` you will need to use `DataColumn` or `DataTable` or `DataRow` to pass the expression as `string` to be evaluated. The `DataColumn.Expression` has a preset expressions such as `AND`, `OR`, `Between` ..etc. So, you can't use any expression that is not supported by the `DataColumn.Expression`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to c# but I will do my best to try out your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Maybe not the most elegant but it seems to work.

```
   public test() {
        List<bool> resultObjects  = new List<bool>();

        List<testobject> tests = new List<testobject>();
        tests.Add(new testobject(Operators.OR, new List<string> {"a","b","c"})); //0
        tests.Add(new testobject(Operators.AND, new List<string> {"d","e"})); //1
        tests.Add(new testobject(Operators.AND, new List<string> {"f","g"})); // 2
        tests.Add(new testobject(Operators.OR, new List<int> {1,2})); //3
        tests.Add(new testobject(Operators.AND, new List<int> {0,3})); //4

        
        Evaluater ev = new Evaluater();
        foreach (testobject test in tests) {
            resultObjects.Add(ev.Evaluate(test.op,test.booleans(resultObjects)));
        }

        bool finalResult = resultObjects.Last();
    }
```

The List of testobjects above can easily be created from an user interface since they only contain plain strings and integers. They represent the logical expression **(a || b || c) && ((d && e) || (f && g))**

The rest of the code:

```
public enum TestType { testOnValues, testOnPreviousResult }
public enum Operators { AND, OR }
public class Evaluater
{
    private Operators andor;
    private List<bool> values;
    public bool Evaluate(Operators _andor, List<bool> _values)
    {
        andor = _andor;
        values = _values;
        if (andor == Operators.AND)
        {
            return And();
        }
        else
        {
            return Or();
        }
    }

    public bool And()
    {
        foreach (bool value in values)
        {
            if (value == false)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public bool Or()
    {
        foreach (bool value in values)
        {
            if (value == true)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class testobject
{
    public Operators op { get; set; }
    private List<bool> values;
    private List<string> dictionaryKeys { get; set; }
    private List<int> resultKeys { get; set; }

    private TestType type;

    public testobject(Operators _op, List<string> _tests)
    {
        op = _op;
        dictionaryKeys = _tests;
        type = TestType.testOnValues;
    }

    public testobject(Operators _op, List<int> _tests)
    {
        op = _op;
        resultKeys = _tests;
        type = TestType.testOnPreviousResult;
    }

    public List<bool> booleans(List<bool> _results) {

        values = new List<bool>();
        if (type == TestType.testOnValues)
        {
            foreach (string s in dictionaryKeys)
            {
                values.Add(Bools.bools[s]);
            }
        }
        if (type == TestType.testOnPreviousResult)
        {
            foreach (int i in resultKeys)
            {
                values.Add(_results[i]);
            }
        }
        return values;

    }
}
public class Bools
{
    public static Dictionary<string, bool> bools = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    static Bools()
    {
        bools.Add("a", true);
        bools.Add("b", false);
        bools.Add("c", true);
        bools.Add("d", false);
        bools.Add("e", false);
        bools.Add("f", false);
        bools.Add("g", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the users to enter arbitrary boolean expression, like "(a && b) || c " then you are going to have to do some parsing. THis is entirely different from what you have shown, where you are typing the expression in code so that teh compiler parses it.

You need logic that takes in a string and works out what's in it, like this

"aha here is an open brace '(', neeed to start sub expression, aha here is 'a' that means 'value of a' , aha  now '&' that might be bitwise and or logical and, whats next , another '&' ok ,logical and, ')' close brace, end of subexpression....."

Irony.net is a c# parser builder https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to c# but I will do my best to try out your suggestion.